# When I plug an USB key, my computer detects it twice

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, hardware-detection

When I plug an USB key, my computer detects it twice. I tried with several USB keys and I always have the same issue. The slots (F:/) and (G:/) are in use. When I click on (F:/), I see nothing in the USB key, and windows tells me that I may want to format it, and when I click on (G:/) I see files in the USB key. However, when I eject (F:/), (G:/) is also ejected, and reciprocally. That's a really boring issue, I already tried to formar my USB keys, but nothing work. Thanks for your help guys, have a great day :)

Comment: It sounds like you might have one those discontinued U2 flashdrives.  It sounds like the device is working as intended.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by that, but I actually don't think so, because this issue is recent. Before it worked **perfectly** :)

Comment: @Ramhound if that were the case, it would only happen with just one USB stick, not with multiple USB Sticks.

Comment: What might help: A screenshot of the disk/partition/volume layouts in the disk management snap-in in compmgmt.msc or diskpart "list volume" from the command line to see what's being assigned F:\ and G:\. Should you find a problem there, just make sure to back it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's 2 partitions in it.

Use some tools like rufus to repartition it.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH. I don't know why there was two partitions, and I think that I have the exact same issue on my other USB keys. Anyways, thanks again. Maybe that's because it was plugged into an old PC and a Mac, I don't know. Thanks bro, have a great day !

Comment: Glad it helps :)